# Android: Best way to add support for more languages

Tags: android, localization

I have an application that was build with all the text in English.  I would like to add more support for other languages, but am concerned about my users who don't necessarily care about the application now having support for Spanish or whatever new language I have added needing to update.  Also, if I am correcting bad translations on a daily basis this would be really annoying to users.

One idea is to make calls to a web service that provides the content for there specific local, which would allow for easy changing if there are bad translations and what have you.  The concern with this is of course the speed.

So is there a right way or a better way to add/change values in the localization without forcing people to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem. And I have one question. Do you think that it will not be annoying for users if your application requests the external service every time when, for instance, new  activity is opened?

To my point of view, you should add support of a language, test the correctness of your translation (for instance, you can ask a user from another country who use your application to check the translation) and only then update your app in the market. If all your string resources are in xml files it is not very difficult to support several languages.

So my proposal for you is at first extract all your string resources into strings.xml file (for default language folder), and then just make several values folders with additional language support.

Comment: No I think the external service would be super annoying, that's why I came here looking for help.  Your point is good, but I don't have control of the translations as much as I would like.  But I suppose this is the best option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding localization is usually (if you followed the good practices) a matter of upgrading a few XML files. So even if the users upgrade, it won't take long at all and they will probably not notice (if they use autoupdate) from the market.

[Check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, but the concern is if the users are getting notifications every day to update languages that they don't care about wouldn't that be annoying?  Is there a way to add more languages without causing the update, such as editing the localized resources in the APK, without forcing an update so only new users get the extra languages.

Comment: It is a reasonable need, but in Android phones all applications do the same, and yes, sometimes is annoying.

Comment: You could always release a separate "international" version, and leave the localization stuff out of the English version.  Then updates are limited to users that wanted some language support.

Comment: @Pieces, nothing forces you to push an update every day. Actually I personally find annoying the applications that do that. I'd prefer grouping updates and pushing them to the users once per month, or so. Basically you, as the author of the app, decides when you push an update.